# how to debug a Type Provider in fsharp?

Tags: debugging, f#, type-providers

I have a COM error inside of my TypeProvider which opens an excel file.

How can I debug it ?
Adding

```
  open System.Diagnostics
  Debug.WriteLine "toto"
  let xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass()
```

I dont know whree the message are going.
Debugview does not show anything either, although I see Excel is trying to load, which happens after after my debug statements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a detailed guide in there :

http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-10-21-61-89/type_2D00_provider_2D00_authoring_2D00_fsharp_2D00_3.0_2D00_developer_2D00_preview.pdf

Section 2.3 explain how you can attach to another devenv.exe, which uses the typeprovider in a script.

Now it breaks on error, and you can set up breakpoints as well.

Comment: The link above is broken.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the document referred to above has morphed into this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/creating-a-type-provider